# How to increase/decrease indentation in Libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice

This should be the simplest thing in the world, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this.

In Word, I use Ctrl+M or Ctrl+Shift+M to increase or decrease (respectively) the indentation of a paragraph. In Libreoffice I can't find the icon that does that. There is an "increase/decrease indent" icon but it doesn't do the same thing as Word - I can only decrease indent within the bullet point hierarchy, even though I want to shift the entire paragraph.

Please help end my frustration...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check if the "Formatting" toolbar is visible: Menu "View" -> "Toolbars". If there's no tick left of "Formatting", left-click to make it visible.

The "Formatting" toolbar has the following buttons by default (undocked / free-floating view):

[image: Screenshot of Formatting toolbar]

To increase / decrease indent, you may use the two buttons:

[image: Increase / decrease Indent buttons],

or use the shortcuts <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> / <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to increase / decrease the indentation.

Since the "Formatting" toolbar has a quite large number of buttons, it may not be displayed completely, as in the following example:

[image]

In this case, just click on the small arrows at the right, to access the "hidden" buttons: [image]

Comment: For me in LibreOffice version 6.1.4.2, the shortcuts `Ctrl + N` and `Alt + N` don't change the indent. `Ctrl + N` creates a new document, and `Alt + N` doesn't do anything. In `Tools > Customize... > Keyboard`, the corresponding functions are `Format > Increase` and `Format > Decrease` (though confusingly, "Increase Indent", "Increase Font Size", and "Increase Paragraph Spacing" are all called "Increase" in this function list)

Comment: @ahiijny: You're right, obviously keyboard shortcuts have changed since the time i've wrote my answer.

Comment: For me, `TAB` increases the indent and `SHIFT + TAB` decreases the indent.

Comment: @SpookyGengar This is not the same thing. When you break a line, the carriage returns to the very beginning and you need to press tab again. Native indentation keeps the level when breaking lines.

Comment: On LibreOffice version 6.4.7.2, use `TAB` and `SHIFT + TAB` as pointed out by SpookyGengar. No button found. I guess this will keep on changing :(

Answer (score 0):

NB this is good for LO Writer 5 on 2020-01-25.

3 solutions to this:

1) some people would say you should invent a new para style and apply that each time you want to have an indent... and presumably a second para style if you want to have which indents twice, etc.
This *seems* an elegant solution because you could potentially change things globally just by tweaking each para style. But para styles in LO are not really versatile enough: supposing you have another reason for differentiating paras which you want to combine with indenting to differing depths? You could soon end up with many different styles... and you would potentially have to tweak all of them.

2) you can assign hotkeys directly to "Increase Indent" and "Decrease Indent": you can find these by going Tools --> Customise --> Keyboard tab --> Functions category: Format, and then setting your hot keys
NB these "indents" are the same as the default tab stops. You can change the default tab stop value if you want by going Tools --> Options --> LibreOffice Writer --> General --> Tab stops (under Settings). This new default tab interval will then apply to all new documents until you change it again.

3) Edit your macros and add this code:

- Tools --> Macros --> Organise macros
- LibreOffice Basic --> expand the item "My Macros" in the box "Macro From"
- expand "Standard" under "My Macros": this should show "Module1"
- with focus on "Main" (or anything) in the "Existing Macros" box, click "Edit"
- add this code at the bottom of the macros dialog which then opens:

-

```
sub increase_indent_1cm
  dim document   as object
  dim dispatcher as object
  document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
  dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")
  dim viewCursor as object
  viewCursor = ThisComponent.CurrentController.getViewCursor()
  viewCursor.ParaLeftMargin = viewCursor.ParaLeftMargin + 1000
end sub

sub decrease_indent_1cm
  dim document   as object
  dim dispatcher as object
  document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
  dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")
  dim viewCursor as object
  viewCursor = ThisComponent.CurrentController.getViewCursor()
  viewCursor.ParaLeftMargin = viewCursor.ParaLeftMargin - 1000
end sub
```

**NB you can put another figure than "1000": 1000 corresponds to 1 cm.**

- close the macros dialog and return to the document.
- now you need to set up hotkeys:
- go to Tools --> Customise --> "Keyboard" Tab
- under "Functions" --> "Category" expand the item "LibreOffice Macros"
- expand "user", expand "Standard" and put the focus on "Module1"
- put the focus on "increase_indent_1cm"
- in the "Shortcut Keys" box select the key combo (hotkey) you want to increase indent: I chose `Ctrl-Shift-[`
- click Modify: the hotkey is now assigned
- do the same for "decrease_indent_1cm": I chose `Ctrl-Shift-]`
- click OK

NB the default tab stop interval (which, as I say above, can be changed) is 1.25 cm. So setting to 1 cm will leave you with different para indents to any tab stops. This may or may not be desirable, depending on your use case.